# Pictures enlarged on front end of Magento 2 store

Tags: magento2, product, product-images

Hi I am using **Magento version 2.0.6**

I have a **live version** of the site and a **local version** running on my pc which i use for testing. as i make changes to the local version i deploy it to the live site.

I'm having a problem on a project i'm working on. The store side images of the live site for products are displaying **extremely large** and somewhat **blurry** and i cant seem to find a solution.I need the live site to display the products like the local site.

The problem is that the pictures on the live version are blurry and enlarged
(see screenshot below of **live site**)
[image: Problem]
The product pictures on my local version are displaying fine (see screenshot below of **local site**)
[image]
Also note that on the live version its displaying **2 products per row** and on the local its **displaying 4 products per row**.

I have compared all the settings in the admin panel for both the live and local sites and they all are the same.

I have did the following things:

- I flushed and refreshed  **all** the **magento 2 cache types**
- I cleared my **browsers cache**
- I ran the command **php bin/magento setup:upgrade**
- I ran the command **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**
- I ran the command **php bin/magento indexer:reindex**

My only conclusion is that it has to be a css or javascript setting?
is there a file i can navigate to and modify perhaps?

Please note that more than one person works on the site.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the product images is set in this file `{theme_directory}/etc/view.xml`

For example :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
            </image>
            <image id="category_page_grid-1" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
            </image>
            <image id="category_page_list" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
            </image>
        </images>
    </media>
</view>
```

Comment: I have checked that file and compared it to my local and they are exactly the same.
Would running the command **php bin/magento catalog:images:resize** help in this regard?

Comment: I'm uncertain if that command will help or not. Does changing the values I posted above have an effect? You'll need to flush the cache after making changes.